# MailCatcher does not work with rbenv on VM

Tags: ruby, virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox, rbenv

I installed MailCatcher in my VM (VirtualBox) managed with rbenv.
But, mailcatcher does not work, puts out error message below:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- i18n/core_ext/string/interpolate (LoadError)
```

It seems that i18n did not install, but I installed it.

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ gem list i18n

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

i18n (0.7.0.beta1)
```

I installed in AWS EC2 as same as that, it works.

What's happen in my VM?

--- details ---

OS: CentOS 6.5

Ruby: 2.1.1 with rbenv 0.4.0

entire error messages:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ mailcatcher--http-ip 192.168.33.12
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- i18n/core_ext/string/interpolate (LoadError)
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/interpolation.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/core_ext/string.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:1:in `each'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.5.12/lib/mail_catcher.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.5.12/bin/mailcatcher:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/mailcatcher:23:in `load'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/mailcatcher:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It might be a problem with the beta version of i18n you're trying to use. Use a released version. Also, the error is coming from activesupport, and not mailcatcher.

Comment: @lassy That's the answer. You should answer your own question and mark it.

Answer (score 3):

Using a combination of the posted answers, here is the solution I came up with:

My environment:

- rbenv
- rails 4.1.8
- i18n (0.7.0.beta1)

My problem:
After running `gem install mailcatcher` in my existing rails project's folder, I ran `mailcatcher` and got:

> `require': cannot load such file -- i18n/core_ext/string/interpolate (LoadError)

I did not want to mess with updating the i18n gem in my existing project's folder as everything in my project was working fine.

Taking @joostvanrijn's advice, I decide to create a separate rails project folder specifically for MailCatcher. I named the folder `mailcatcher`.
In my newly created `/mailcatcher` folder, I ran `gem install mailcatcher`. Then I ran `gem update i18n`, which got me to `i18n-0.7.0`.
Finally, I called `mailcatcher` and it ran without a hitch.

Later, I ran into another issue with MailCatcher:

While I could get to `http://127.0.0.1:1080`, sending emails would fail with

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error
>
> Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)

I tried to quit MailCatcher by going to `http://127.0.0.1:1080` and clicking "Quit", but that would just take me to http://mailcatcher.me and not actually kill the process.

To kill the process, I used `lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP` to find the processes running on `127.0.0.1:1025` and `127.0.0.1:1080` and used `kill -9 PID`.

I learned from this [Discourse post](https://meta.discourse.org/t/problems-with-mailcatcher-in-dev-environment/23412/6) that `Net::ReadTimeout` is due to a bug in MailCatcher and the workaround is to run MailCatcher in the foreground using `mailcatcher -f`. That solved my problem and now I can "catch" emails without issue. Yay!

Answer (score 2):

rails 4.2 beta / activesupport-4.2.0.beta2 depends on i18n (< 0.8, >= 0.7.0.beta1).

mailcatcher (0.5.12) throws your error if it loads the beta gem of i18n.

If you're not using rails 4.2 beta then you could uninstall the beta version

```
gem uninstall i18n -v i18n-0.7.0.beta1
```

This is referenced in multiple issues with the gem

https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/164

https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/155

Answer (score 1):

For anyone encountering this issue with rbenv: I've found a workaround. Make sure you use a ruby version that does not have the rails 4.2 beta gem installed. (I had an older project which i cd'd into and from there i had no problem installing and running mailcatcher.

It's not unlikely that you have to create a new folder (named "mailcatcher" for example) create a .ruby-version with the supported version so you can run mailcatcher from there

Answer (score 0):

I'm using rails 4.2 too and solved my problem installing another ruby version for mailcatcher.

I'm using RVM and ruby 2.1.5 for rails, so, I just installed and used 2.1.4 for mailcatcher:

```
rvm install 2.1.4 --with-readline-dir=/usr/include/readline
rvm 2.1.4
gem install mailcatcher
mailcatcher
```

Using rbenv you could do:

```
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-readline-dir=/usr/include/readline" rbenv install 2.1.4
rbenv shell 2.1.4
gem install mailcatcher
mailcatcher
```

It's not the perfect solution, but is a good workaround until mailcatcher fixes this.